# Failing to recover from hibernate

Tags: 11.10, hibernate

Im having a problem with ubuntu, its not recovering from hibernate.

The system will actually hibernate correctly (ive installed uspwsusp so i can see whats happening), but when i restart my laptop, i get a solid purple screen (not the usual ubuntu splash screen), and it seems to wait for a while (~10s), before dropping onto the usual ubuntu bootup screen, where it goes on to do a standard boot process.

Is there anyway i can get hibernate to work properly?

Im using ubuntu 11.10 x64

Comment: Logs regarding hibernate/wakeup/suspend/resume are in `/var/log/pm-*.log`. Can you "suspend" and recover?

Comment: This question appears to be abandoned, if you are experiencing a similar issue please [ask a new question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/ask) with details pertaining to your problem. If you feel this question is *not* abandoned, please flag the question explaining that. :)

Comment: @richzilla Are you still experiencing this issue?

Comment: This question appears to be abandoned and unanswered, could you perhaps add more detail to your question? If this question no longer applies then you can either delete it or answer it yourself if you've solved the problem.  This is to help with the Ask Ubuntu Clean Up. If you feel this question is *not* abandoned, please flag the question explaining that. :)