# Swap partition is not recognized

Tags: hibernate, swap

I think this problem might be related to this one:

[Failing to recover from hibernate](https://askubuntu.com/q/84551/2978)

Basically, as soon as ive installed ubuntu, using the automatic partitioning, if i run gparted and look at my disk partitions, my swap space is displayed as unknown, with an exclamation mark next to it:

[image: Error image]

Ok, next step, i manually assign the 'unknown' section to be a swap partition, and attempt to hibernate. When i switch my system back on, it runs as described in the link above, failing to restore from hibernate. When i run gparted again after its restarted, the swap partition is back to 'unknown'. Any idea whats going on here?

Comment: So if I understand correctly, everytime you restore from hibernation, then the swap partition becomes raw?

Comment: yep, every time i attempt to hibernate

Comment: I am not sure why this is happening. The closest I could find was [this on Unix StackExchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/8827/hibernate-to-disk-not-restoring-but-suspend-to-ram-is-working)

Answer (score 2):

If you've chosen to encrypt your user-directory during the installation, Ubuntu will automatically encrypt your swap. This could be the Problem in this case.
You can check your /etc/fstab for the device that is mounted as swap. If it's something like /dev/mapper/cryptswap1 your swap is encrypted and hibernate can't work.

Answer (score 0):

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ecryptfs/+bug/432785

Comment: Can you state whether there is a workaround for the OP?